# How to unwrap object in http post response in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post, google-cloud-functions

How do I unwrap an object received from an HTTP POST request?

Here is my code:

```
this.http.post(url, user, httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result.status);
});
```

I am getting the error on the console.log()

```
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

How do I unwrap the result variable/response object so I can read the individual values in typescript?

If I console.log(result), I can see all the values.

Comment: post what you get once you run console.log(result)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `observe: 'response'` if you want the whole `HttpResponse` in your `httpOptions`. The default behaviour is `observe: 'body'`, which returns an `Observable` of the response body. This is also described [here.](http://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwhneu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demonstrating how this should work (see console output).

```
this.http.post(url, user, {
   ...httpOptions, // or specifiy it inside httpOptions directly
   observe: 'response'
}).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result.status);
});
```

The error you are getting is a TypeScript error though. The response is inferred as type `Object` - which obviously doesn't have any `status` property. Usually, the types should be correct. You could go around the issue by typecasting the response to `any`.

```
this.http.post(url, user, httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
  console.log((result as any).status); // Take the type information away for this statement
});
```

To be honest, I wouldn't suggest doing that though. You should investigate why the response is inferred as `Object` in the first place.

Comment: "If I console.log(result), I can see all the values. " I guess this has nothing to do with httpOptions

Comment: That's strange. Seems correct what you're doing, as is stated here https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: @robert Added more information on what the actual problem is. I'm still not sure why the types are wrong here...